# Proof verification - Minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has integer coef.s iff its an alg. integer

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I want to prove the following theorem:

**Theorem.** The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has integer coefficients if and only if $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer.

Here is what I have done and I want to ask whether it has any problematic parts or not:

($\implies$) part is trivial. For the converse, let $q(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. Then, since $q(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, $f(X)=q(X)r(X)$ for some $r(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Assume that $q$ has at least one non-integer coefficient. Define

$ V = lcm\{$denominators of coefficients of $q(X) \}$.

$ U = lcm\{$denominators of coefficients of $r(X) \}$. Then,

$UVf(X) \equiv 0$ modulo ($UV$) but $Vq(X)Ur(X) \equiv UVq(X)r(X) \not \equiv 0$ . So, I think we are done.

Comment: Where does your proof use the fact that $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer?

Comment: While I am saying that $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: But for every algebraic number $\alpha$ there's a polynomial $f(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. It just need not be monic.

Comment: The notes I follow defines it a number satisfying a monic polynomial with integer coefficients and I am taking it as $f$.

Comment: I agree that $Vq(X) $ and $Ur(X) $ are non-zero modulo $UV$. But how can we argue that the product $Vq(X)Ur(X) $ is also non-zero modulo $UV$? The problem is that $\mathbb Z_{(UV)}[X]$ is not necessarily an integral domain, so there may exist non-trivial zero-divisors in $\mathbb Z_{(UV)}[X]$. Have you considered picking a prime $p | UV$, and reducing modulo $p$? This would help, because $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ **is** an integral domain.

Comment: @KennyWong I could not find out how to prove it that way, yet.

Comment: @Ninja Okay, I've provided some clarifications below.

Comment: I'm a little confused, normally the definition of an algebraic integer is that $m_\alpha(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$, what definition are you working with?

Comment: The definition that I am using is that $\alpha$ is a root of some monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. It only says that it is monic. After that, there is a proposition which says that "$\alpha$ is an algebraic integer $\iff m_\alpha(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. So it does not says that the minimal polynomial of it has integer coefficients but it satisfies a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, the lemma we need to prove is:

> Suppose $f(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$ is a monic polynomial, and suppose $f(X) =q(X)r(X)$, where $q(X)$ and $r(X)$ are monic polynomials in $\mathbb Q[X]$. Then $q(X)$ is in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

I'll try my best  to guide you through a proof that incorporates as many of your ideas as possible.

- Define $V$ and $U$ to be the smallest positive integers such that $Vq(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$ and $Ur(X) \in \mathbb Z[X]$. I invite you to check that the greatest common divisor of the coefficients of $Vq(X)$ is one. The same is true of the coefficients of $Ur(X)$. While checking this, it is important to think about why we need $q(X)$ and $r(X)$ to be monic.
- Suppose, for contradiction, that $V > 1$. Then there exists a prime number $p$ that divides $V$. Consider the equation
  $$ (Vq(X))(Ur(X)) = UVf(X)$$
  as an equation in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$. I encourage you to show that $UVf(X)$ is zero in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$, and that $Vq(X)$ and $Ur(X)$ are non-zero in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$.
- Finally, you can think about how this contradicts the fact that $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ is a integral domain, and hence, conclude that $V = 1$.

So the idea of this argument is very similar to your argument, except that we are working in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ rather than $\mathbb Z_{(UV)}[X]$. The latter is not necessarily  an integral domain, and that is the important difference.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the definition you have of algebraic integer is “a root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients”.

Your attempt at a proof is invalid: there is no justification of the main step. Moreover “modulo $UV$” means you are working in a ring with zero divisors.

Thus one direction is obvious. For the other one, let $f(X)$ be the (monic) minimal polynomial of the algebraic integer $\alpha$ and let $g(X)$ be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients such that $g(\alpha)=0$.

Then $g(X)=f(X)q(X)$ for some $q(X)\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

We can write
$$
g(X)=\frac{a}{b}f_1(X)\cdot\frac{c}{d}q_1(X)
$$
where $f_1$ and $q_1$ have integer coefficients and greatest common divisor of the coefficients equal to $1$ (that is, they are primitive). It's not restrictive to assume the leading coefficient of $f_1(X)$ is positive.

Therefore
$$
bdg(X)=acf_1(X)q_1(X)
$$
Since $f(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $f_1$ is primitive, also $f_1(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (Gauss’ lemma). Due to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ being a UFD, $f_1(X)$ is prime and so it divides $g(X)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, because it divides neither $b$ nor $d$.

Hence $g(X)=f_1(X)q_2(X)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and, comparing the leading coefficients, we conclude the leading coefficient of $f_1$ is $1$. Therefore $f_1(X)=f(X)$, because $f_1(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: Can you explain how did you write $$
g(X)=\frac{a}{b}f_1(X)\cdot\frac{c}{d}q_1(X)
$$?

Comment: @Ninja First let $b$ be the least common multiple of the coefficients in $f$; express each coefficient as having $b$ as denominator, then take $a$ as lhe least common multiple of the numerators. Do similarly with $q$.